# Should I use the Nouveau Gallium 3D driver?

Tags: 11.04, drivers, nouveau

Does the Nouveau 3D driver works with Ubuntu Natty Narwhal?

What are the drawbacks of using this driver, i.e. is there any chance of breaking the desktop using this driver?

The Nvidia driver will not install and I can only use Unity 2D.

Thank you.

Comment: 1-Yes it works, 2-depends on your graphics card, 3-if anything goes wrong when installing it, probably.. 4-why it doesnt install?

Answer (score 2):

It's easy to test, just install the package

```
libgl1-mesa-dri-experimental
```

If for whatever reason it doesn't work, boot into recovery mode (press and hold the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key when powering on the system to get the GRUB menu, then choose the recovery entry), select *Drop to a root shell prompt* and run:

```
apt-get purge libgl1-mesa-dri-experimental
```

The drawback: its performance isn't on par with Nvidia's binary driver, but even with old cards it should be enough to run Compiz/Unity (given that there are no compatibility issues).

Answer (score 0):

Did it work in ubuntu, Fedora 16 uses the Gallium 0.4 on NV46 for my Nvidia 7400 card in gnome 3 and it works perfekt here!